# Equivalent formula of Laplace Beltrami operator on Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

We want to prove that given the formula $\Delta_gu=-g^{ij}\delta_{ij}u+g^{ij}\Gamma^k_{ij}\delta_ku$ gives the formula $\Delta_gu=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\delta_i(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ij}\delta_ju)$

I am reading a note which does the following step which I don't understand
$g^{ij}\Gamma^k_{ij}\delta_ku= \frac{1}{2}g^{ij}g^{kl}(\delta_ig_{jl}+\delta_jg_{il}-\delta_lg_{ij})\delta_ku
=-\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}g_{jl}\delta_ig^{ij}\delta_ku-\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}g_{il}\delta_jg^{ij}\delta_ku-\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}g^{kl}\delta_lg_{ij}\delta_k u$

I couldn't understand this step how $\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}g^{kl}\delta_ig_{jl}\delta_ku=-\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}g_{jl}\delta_ig^{ij}\delta_k u$ any hints would be very much helpful.

Comment: Alternative: Show that $\Delta u = \div \nabla u$. The coordinate formula for $X = \nabla u$ is easy to derive. The coordinate formula for $\div X$ is easy to derive if you define $\div$ using the Lie derivative of the volume form, in which case it is an exercise in differential forms, or if you define $\div$ as the formal adjoint of $-\nabla$, in which case the proof is integration by parts in coordinates.

Comment: Your last equality is wrong. You are missing some $\delta_ku$ on the LHS.

Comment: Right fixed it but how they made it equal to RHS where we had $\delta_ig^{ij}$ which is the inverse matrix of $g_{ij}$ whereas in RHS we have $\delta_ig_{jl}$

Comment: @Mason The command `\div` doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, just interpret $\div$ as $\text{div}$.

Comment: $\frac{\partial \delta^i_l}{\partial x^i}\equiv 0$ so $\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}\left(g^{ij}g_{jl}\right)=0$ or using the Leibniz (product) rule $$g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial x^i}=-g_{jl}\frac{\partial g^{ij}}{\partial x^i}$$

Comment: Oh ok thanks that was easy. I was just noticing it differently